# Click effect/animation for all application

Tags: java, android, animation, click

It is possible to create a click effect/animation for all clicks on my application?

[image: example]

Since I want this behaviour for all clicks events on my application, how should I do this? Is this bad for performance or resources of the smartphone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a day working at this I managed to accomplish the expected behaviour.

Basically, I create my own Activity class which will do the animation work with the help of a custom lib. I'll try to explain what I did for future reference:

**1. Add this lib to your project:**

```
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.3'
```

**2. Add these dimens to your "dimens.xml" file:**

```
<dimen name="click_animation">100dp</dimen>
<dimen name="click_compensation">50dp</dimen>
```

**3. Make the top parent of your activities layout a "RelativeLayout" and set a custom id:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main_layout">

    ... the rest of the layout ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

**4. Create your own "Activity" class:**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

    public void setClickAnimation(final Activity activity) {
        // if you want to change the size of the animation, change the size on the dimens.xml
        int size = (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.click_animation);
        params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);

        // you want the parent layout of the activity
        final RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // you maybe won't need this compensation value
                    int compensation = (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.click_compensation);
                    try { startAnimation(view, (int) event.getX() - compensation, (int) event.getY() - compensation); }
                    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void startAnimation(RelativeLayout view, int x, int y) throws IOException {
        params.leftMargin = x;
        params.topMargin = y;

        // those are from the lib you imported
        final GifImageView anim = new GifImageView(this);
        // if you don't have it yet, put the gif you want on the assets folder
        final GifDrawable gifFromResource = new GifDrawable(getAssets(), "click_animation.gif");
        gifFromResource.addAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationCompleted(int loopNumber) {
                anim.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                gifFromResource.stop();
                gifFromResource.recycle();
            }
        });

        anim.setBackground(gifFromResource);
        gifFromResource.start();

        view.addView(anim, params);
    }
}
```

**5. Make your Activities extend your "Activity" class:**

```
public class FirstScreen extends MyActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cards_screen);

        // call the method you created and pass the activity context
        setClickAnimation(this);
    }
}
```

As for resources spent: this looks like a good solution and I am getting a good performance. The application seems to not be wasting a lot of resources with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know without understanding the stack that has been built, that being said I think there are some safer and less methodologies to an onclick event that is the same across the board. For one I would not change fundamental nature of the "onClick" function, the lower level you mess with the more dangerous it is. That being said I think I would create my own version/function of onclick, maybe boomClick, where boomClick creates the animation that you want. Referencing a single function will barely decrease performance at all.